# Parsing host:port expressions

Tags: c#, parsing, uri

What's the best and simplest way to parse an environment variable of the following possible forms: `host[:port]`

- `redis`
- `redis:6379`
- `10.0.0.72`
- `10.0.0.72:6379`
- `my.domain.name`
- `my.domain.name:6379`

The inputs are never prepended with a protocol.

The end goal is to parse out the host and port in order to create an object of type `System.Net.IPEndPoint`, possibly after using `Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0]` depending on whether there is an ip or a hostname supplied in the environment variable.

The purpose is helping dotnet core apps inside various docker containers discover each other according to values specified in their environment variables.

I'm hoping to make use of parsing utilities already available in the dotnet core libraries rather than roll my own parser.

`new Uri("redis:6379")` produces invalid results.

`new Uri("https://redis:6379")` produces a Uri object with correct host and port properties, but it seems ridiculous to me that it should be necessary to malform all the inputs by prepending "https://" just to get the Uri object to parse it correctly.

`new Uri("https://redis")` incorrectly sets the `Port` property as 443 and doesn't indicate that it wasn't supplied in the user input.

If it's possible to skip parsing steps and resolve straight to IPEndPoint with no in-between steps, that would be my preferred answer.

This is what I'm using at the moment, with error handling removed. Have you got something better?

```
IPEndPoint ParseGateway(string input) {
    var parts = input.Split(':');
    var host = parts[0];
    var port = parts.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(parts[1]) : DEFAULT_GATEWAY_PORT;
    var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
    return new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
}
```

Comment: if i understood correctly then why not you use string.split method to get host and port ?

Comment: @Agent_Orange, that's what I'm currently using, as you can see at the bottom of my question - I'm looking for a better solution, preferably using methods provided by the framework.

Comment: Remember that IPv6 literal addresses use colons as separators. The equivalent of `128.0.0.1:80` is `[::1]:80` and a rough equivalent of `10.0.0.72:6379` is `[fd12:3456:789a:1::]:6379`. So a simple split is not future-proof. Instead, tacking on a scheme and using a URI parser would be easier in the long run.

Comment: Prepending a scheme for `System.Uri` is probably the way to go.  Since "https://" assumes port 443 you could just use a nonsense scheme like "tcp://" or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use string method SubString as shown below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                  "redis",
                  "redis:6379",
                  "10.0.0.72",
                  "10.0.0.72:6379",
                  "my.domain.name",
                  "my.domain.name:6379"
            };
            string address = "";
            string port = "";
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                if (input.Contains(":"))
                {
                    address = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(":"));
                    port = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(":") + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    address = input;
                    port = "";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Address : '{0}'; Port : '{1}'", address, port);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is better or different than the implementation I'm currently using, shown at the bottom of my question.

Comment: This approach won't handle IPv6 addresses correctly either.

Comment: @Dai : :Look at date of responses.  IPV6 was not part of the original issue.

Comment: This comment from 2019 ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217485/parsing-hostport-expressions/49217774?noredirect=1#comment104249141_49217485 ) specifically mentions IPv6 too, soooo